# VB.net Count multiples of specific items in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, count, listbox

I've had a look around the internet for a few hours and found nothing to help my situation which I think is quite a common one.

I would like to count specific items in my list box and find out how many there are of each one. I wanna assign this value to a variable. I think I have most of it covered however I cannot get the code to work.

To explain I want something where it counts how many 'Garlic Bread' I have in the list and then assign it to a variable like 'item1' and so on for all the items.

Cheers

Comment: Would you mind posting your code?

Comment: you dont need a GUI control for that, use a List(Of String) to count items instances.  You might want to then post the filtered results to a ListBox or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class MyListItem
    Public Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
        LiId = id
        LiName = name
    End Sub

    Public LiId As Integer
    Public LiName As String
End Class

Private Sub Test()
    Dim listbox2 As New ListBox()

    Dim list As New List(Of MyListItem)()
    list.Add(New MyListItem(1, "a"))
    list.Add(New MyListItem(2, "a"))
    list.Add(New MyListItem(3, "b"))
    list.Add(New MyListItem(4, "c"))
    listbox2.DataSource = list
    listbox2.ValueMember = "LiId"
    listbox2.DisplayMember = "LiName"

    Dim countOfA = Aggregate itm In DirectCast(listbox2.DataSource, List(Of MyListItem))
            Where itm.LiName = "a"
            Into Sum(1)


End Sub
```

Result: countOfA = 2

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, I would up vote it but I'm not a high enough level :( . Is it possible you could explain the 'mylistitem' parts of the code as I'm not quite sure if I should be renaming that to the items I want in the list as VB says they are not defined correctly? Cheers

Comment: When you say, `List.Items.Add`, it takes object. So, when you do `...Add(myString)` your object is string. And you can do it. Or you can add your custom object, which has many properties. Or, if you have ready collection of items, you can set this collection to be the Datasource and mark which property is value and which is display. WinForms will take care of displaying it. In this example (and it is working one) I showed how to use collection of custom objects to fill the list, how to retrieve it, and how aggregate single group and get the count